Texture masks and colors being washed out with each mix shader node added
on the topic of creating custom textures, I always run into the same problem when creating custom masks and colors for said textures.
In my current project, I'm trying to create a label for a perfume bottle, however, even at the first mix shader I'm encountering issues.
This is the material preview for the mask I created. As seen, the color is vibrant without any issues.


However, once it is plugged into the mix shader, the color dulls and is washed out.


And subsequently, with more masks and mix shaders added, it just gets worse.


These are what the separate masks look like:

This has always happened in my previous projects and I still don't understand why.
Is this a problem with my masking or something else?

Your label is in the shadow. Have you tried to light it up?

Hello could you please pack the images and share your file?

What on Earth are you doing there? The first Mix Shader at the bottom left mixes a white Principled BSDF with nothing - that creates a white card surface with pitch black (= shadeless) rim and text. Then you mix in a white text over the black text. Then you mix a white rim over the black rim, leaving you with a completely white card (except for some antialiasing perhaps at the boundaries between the different parts). And like @DanielMöller already said, your label is in the shadow. The Material Preview uses some default HDRI lighting.

If you are plugging an Image Texture directly into the Output it will work as if you'd use an Emission shader, as soon as you plug it into a Principled BSDF it will work as a Diffuse, it won't emit light anymore and it will be subject to lights and shadows. Also it makes no sense to use a Mix Shader that mixes a Principled BSDF with nothing, plug your Image Texture into the Principled BSDF that you plug into the Output and add a light in your scene to get the label lit.

I did not say mixing with nothing doesn't make sense, if someone wanted shadeless black in those parts that's the easiest way to achieve it  What doesn't make sense is having one mask that leaves rim and text black and then use inverted masks that basically erase the previous separation.

Thanks for the explanation, I made the stupid mistake of just missing out lighting for my label. Once I added a light directly on it, the colors didn't look "washed out" anymore
Thanks everyone!

The problem of the first image you posted is that your label is in the shadow.
There is no light on it. Add some light in front, or rotate the sun.
The last "nodes" setup is using "non-color" for two of the image textures. They should all be using "sRGB".
You also need to add some shader to the first mix, leaving it empty will probably give you some unwanted results.

He is using them as mix factor, it is a very common practice and even better in many cases to use Non-Color instead of sRGB if you want to use black and white or greyscale images as float values for masks. However what he does and what I mention in my comment is that he uses the masks to mix white materials with white materials which of course results in everything just being white. Leaving the second shader empty in the first mix doesn't matter since he's "overwriting" it in the following mixes anyway.

As stated above in the answer, you were right, I just needed to add a light to the label. Thank you!
